# spring batch flatfileitemreader input resource must exist error

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to spring and my java is rusty so please excuse me if this is a simple question.

I have a two step job. The first step is to query a MongoDB and write a file. The second step is to read the file and process it.

I am using FlatFileItemReader for the second step. In the first step, I am writing the file without specifying any path.

When I run the job from within sts, the first step creates the file in the project directory in my sts workspace folder.

The second step throws the input resource must exist exception. I tried a variety of options such as file://, file:/ and so on without any success.

Confused as to why the read doesn't look for the file in the same place that the write wrote to.

In any case, any help in resolving the issue will be appreciated.

The first step does not use a FlatFileItemWriter and is just a tasklet that writes the file using java.

Here's the config:

```
    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="customerItemReader" processor="customerProcessor" writer="mongodbItemWriter"
                commit-interval="1">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>


</batch:job>


<bean id="loadFromMongo" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter">
     <property name="targetObject">
      <bean class="testMongo.MongoLoader"/>
  </property>
 <property name="targetMethod" value="loadFromMongo" />
</bean>

 <bean id="customerItemReader"
  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
 <property name="resource" value="classpath:Customers.txt"/>

<property name="lineMapper" ref="customerLineMapper"/>
```

```
<bean id="customerLineMapper"
     class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
 <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="customerLineTokenizer"/>
 <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="customerFieldSetMapper"/>
```

```
<bean id="customerLineTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
</bean>

<bean id="customerFieldSetMapper" class="testMongo.CustomerFieldSetMapper"> 
</bean>

<bean id="customerProcessor" class="testMongo.CustomerItemProcessor"> 
</bean>

<bean id="mongodbItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter">
    <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
    <property name="collection" value="creditReport" />
</bean>


<!--  commenting out copied stuff from mkyong SpringBatch Example for now
<bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="record" />
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/report.xml" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="reportUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">

    <property name="aliases">
        <util:map id="aliases">
            <entry key="record" value="com.mkyong.model.Report" />


        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
 -->
```

Comment: Why do use a `Tasklet` for this?  Also, can you share your config?

Comment: Make a breakpoint at the line where FlatFileItemReader is checking for the existence of the file. Then have a look what kind of Resource it is and to which location it is pointing to.

Comment: I had some trouble with the MongoItemReader so thought I could do it with a tasklet.

Comment: Added the config to the original post